# linalg.matrix_power(A,n) for a huge $n$ and a huge $A$

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to use linalg to find $P^{500}$ where $ P$ is a 9x9 matrix but Python displays the following:
[Matrix full of inf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll47k.png)

I think this is too much for this method so my question is, there is annother library to find $P^{500}$? Must I surrender?
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the eigendecomposition and then exponentiate the matrix of eigenvalues. Like this. You end up getting an inf up in the first column. Unless you control the type of matrix by their eigenvalues this won't happen I believe. In other words, your eigenvalues have to be bounded. You can generate a random matrix by the [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) putting the eigenvalues along the diagonal. This is a post I have about generating a matrix with given [eigenvalues.](https://linearalgebra.quora.com/Generating-a-matrix-with-integer-eigenvalues) This should be the way that method works anyways.

```
    % Generate random 9x9 matrix
    n=9;
    A = randn(n);
   [V,D] = eig(A);
   p = 500;
   Dp = D^p;
   Ap = V^(-1)*Dp*V;

   Ap1 = mpower(A,p);
```

Answer (score 0):

NumPy arrays have homogeneous data types and float datatype maximum is

```
>>> np.finfo('d').max
1.7976931348623157e+308

>>> _**0.002
4.135322944991858

>>> np.array(4.135)**500
1.7288485271474026e+308

>>> np.array(4.136)**500
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
inf
```

So if there is an inner product that results higher than approx. 4.135 it is going to blowup and once it blows up, the next product will be multiplied with infinities and more entries will get infinities until everything becomes infinities.

Metahominid's suggestion certainly helps but it will not solve the issue if your eigenvalues are larger than this value. In general, you need to use specialized high-precision tools to get correct results.